# Как импортировать изображение в SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas, telegram-bot

Есть функция она импортирует только текстовые данные (использую). Хотят чтобы бот еще показал фото человека контакты которому принадлежат.

Вопросы:

1. Как правильно вставить изображение в  Excel?
2. Как импортировать изображение из Excel в SQLite?

Функция

```
import pandas as pd

def import_phone_db_new(message):
    dfs = pd.read_excel(PHONE.XLSX, sheet_name=None)
    conn = sqlite3.connect(phone.db)
    for tab, df in dfs.items():
        df.to_sql(tab, conn, index=False, if_exists='replace')
    now_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    msg = "Импортировано в {}.".format(now_time)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, msg, parse_mode='HTML')
```

Comment: Ну вообще в базах данных обычно хранят не сами изображения а путь к ним, т.е. получаешь путь и на месте по этому пути просто подгружаешь изображение

Comment: если очень хочется то можно создать поле Blob и байты картинки туда вписать.

Comment: @alex поле фото Blob `df.to_sql(tab, conn, index=False, if_exists='replace', dtype={'photo':'BLOB'})`, как теперь в єксель вставить байты картинки